# Taskbar clock not updating

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I've noticed recently that the clock on my taskbar has been freezing, but when I click anywhere on the taskbar, it displays the correct time. I'm guessing this is some sort of issue with the taskbar not updating.

What might be causing this issue? Is there something I could do that might fix it?

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/582096/how-can-i-restart-my-taskbar and the comment of Moshe Katz ...

Comment: It looks to me that the issue in that question is more severe than mine, given that I can make the clock update by clicking the bar.