# Windows 7 volume control

Tags: windows-7

The volume bar is stuck in lower left screen. I cannot use it or get rid of it. I cannot reach the task bar volume icon because it is covered by the stuck volume bar. What other steps can I take?

Comment: Correction - The volume bar is stuck in the lower RIGHT screen, not left screen.

Comment: What steps *have* you taken? Have you tried logging off and logging back in? Rebooting?

Comment: Restart explorer [How can I restart my taskbar?](http://superuser.com/a/721578)

Answer (score 1):

some win7 'painting' problems can be solved by changing the theme and then changing it back, and there is a pretty good chance doing that will solve it the quickest way.

Comment: Or by restarting explorer ...

Comment: @DavidPostill changing theme solves it more often.

Comment: one example of changing theme solving it where end tasking explorer didn't was here http://superuser.com/questions/669860/how-can-i-remove-an-unwanted-fragment-of-old-gui-on-my-screen    On another occasion  I had the same issue as the OP(shadow of a clicked  volume control covering over the icon) and it may be end tasking exlorer didn't solve it but changing theme did.